# Why i can not use reference variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
namespace LanguageFeatures.Models
{
   public class Product
   {
       private string name;

       public string Name
       {
           get { return name; }
           set { name = value; }
       }

        //public int Test { get; set; }
   }

    //class TestProperty
    //{
    //    Product p = new Product{Name = "asd"};
    //    p.

    //}
}
```

in line number 15 i cannot use p.
From controller i can use it. But when i want to access from model folder i can not access it.
Why i can not use reference variable?

Comment: Please put the code in your question instead of an image.

Comment: It would be much better if you post your code rather than a screen shot of it.

Comment: That's not valid C#

Comment: `p` is a class level field you can use it in method or property.

Comment: You need to clear your basics of C#. Refer to the answer given by Jakub Szumiato. He has provided example code for you

Comment: Why i am getting so many negative votes? I replace my snapshot with code. Now negative vote should be removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to write execution code inside of a class.
Please close it in a method, or any other execution code block and it will be ok.

Following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/class

A class can contain declarations of the following members:

- Constructors
- Constants
- Fields
- Finalizers
- Methods
- Properties
- Indexers
- Operators
- Events
- Delegates
- Classes
- Interfaces
- Structs

I have added below some code to illustrate the usage from constructor, following the comments.

Hope this clarifies. Happy learning c#!

```
using System;

namespace LanguageFeatures.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        //field
        private string name;

        //property
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public int Test { get; set; }

    }
    public class TestProperty
    {
        //constructor
        public TestProperty()
        {
            Product p = new Product { Name = "asd", Test = 1 };
            Console.WriteLine(p.Test.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be beneficial to write some code that demonstrates what you mean. I suspect the question asker might not understand.

Comment: @sab669 TBH, this answer is very clear, in my opinion what is needed here is an introductory book on C# and some practice.

Answer (score 4):

You can use it but not directly within class but rather inside a method body

```
public class TestProperty
{
  public void TestMethod()
  {
     Product p = new Product {Name = "asd"};
     Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error, that generates your compiler, already should have answered to your question:

> Error CS0236 - A field initializer **cannot** reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Product.[something]'